# PHP Laravel protected route for subpage without authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a `Laravel`-app and I have a route where I need to include a third-party script/iframe. I want to protect that route with a simple access code without setting up the `laravel`-authentication.

Is that possible? If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You mean everytime you want to access that route, you will have to provide a code? Is that in api or web routes?

Comment: @pr1nc3 yes exactly, each time someone hits that route, they should enter an acces-code, like forexample "1234" or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solutions I give below suggest you are trying to access your route with `code=X` URI/GET parameter.

## Simple Route

You can simply check for the given code to be correct in each route's method, and redirect somewhere if that's not the case.

**`web.php`**

```php
Route::get('yourRouteUri', 'YourController@yourAction');
```

**`YourController.php`**

```php
use Request;

class YourController extends Controller {
    public function yourAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->code != '1234') {
             return route('route-to-redirect-to')->redirect();
        }

        return view('your.view');
    }
}
```

## Route with middleware

Or you can use middlewares for avoiding to repeat the condition-block in each route if you have many of them concerned by your checking.

**`app/Http/Middleware/CheckAccessCode.php`**

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Request;
use Closure;

class CheckAccessCode
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->code != '1234') {
            return route('route-to-redirect-to')->redirect();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**`app/Http/Kernel.php`**

```php
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // Other middlewares...    

    'withAccessCode' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAccessCode::class,
];
```

**`web.php`**

```php
Route::get('yourRouteUri', 'YourController@yourAction')->middleware('withAccessCode');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware).

Register the middleware in the `$routesMiddleware` of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

Then use it like this:

```
Route::get('script/iframe', 'YourController@index')->middleware('your_middleware');
```

-- EDIT

You can access the route like this:

```
yoururl.com/script/iframe?code=200
```

Then in the middleware `handle` method:

```
if ($request->code !== 200) {
  // you don't have access redirect to somewhere else
}

// you have access, so serve the requested page.
return $next($request);
```

Comment: OK but how can I make this new middleware to accept a specific code the user must enter to access that route?

Comment: Did you checked the documentation? You can pass it in the `request` as a parameter and then compare using the `request` object in the middleware.

Comment: OK, but when I do `if (!$request->access == '1234') { return redirect('/'); }` all my other routes don't work :-s

Comment: Did you created a custom middleware for this? Is this middleware used only to protect one single route as I gave you the example above?

Comment: `!$request->access` will equal `true` or `false`, so `!$request->access == '1234'` will return `false`. (but that's an other issue)